# magento catalog price rules disappear sometimes

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog-price-rules

My store is running on magento 1.8.1  CE.

The catalog price rules are working fine and being set every noght with a cron.

But sometimes during the day the price rules disappear ...
I can solve it again by pressing the set catatlog rules, but i am missing a lot of conversipon trough this problem.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: So Catalog Price Rules and the 'Set Catalog Rules' is a module, I'm guessing. Can you give us a bit more information about the setup? Which Module, How are the Rules Stored etc? Edit the question to expand upon it.

Comment: The catalog price rules are built-in in magento. The rules are stored in a mysql database. And being set every night through cron